# Recurrence criterion for a specific Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)$ be a Markov chain on $\mathbb N_0$ defined by $(\alpha \geq 0)$

$$ p(0,1) = 1 \\ p(x,x+1) = 1-\frac{1}{(1+x)^\alpha} \\ p(x,0)= \frac{1}{(1+x)^\alpha}$$

Define the shifted moments for the first time step $X_1$ as

$$ m_1(x)=\mathbb E[X_1 - x\vert X_0=0], m_2(x)=\mathbb E[(X_1 - x)^2\vert X_0=0] $$

Now consider the case $\alpha = 1$. We have $m_1(x)=0, m_2(x) =x$. Somehow, one can deduce the following (for small $\epsilon > 0$)

$$ m_1(x) \leq \frac{(1-\epsilon)}{2x} m_2(x) \Rightarrow (X_n) \text{ is reccurent for } \alpha=1$$

How does this inequality imply the original definition of reccurrence, i.e. $\mathbb P(\tau_x < \infty \vert X_0=x)=1$, where $\tau_x:= \inf\{n\geq 1 \vert X_n=x\}$ is the first hitting time?

Comment: I don't understand the relation of the variables $m_1$ and $m_2$ since in this case they are deterministic and equal to $1-x$ and $(1-x)^2$ respectively.

Anyways you can easily check in the case $\alpha = 1$ that $P(X_1=1, \ldots , X_n=n | X_0=0) = \frac{1}{n}$ and by taking limits
$P(X_i = i, i \geq 1 | X_0=0) = P(T_0 < \infty | X_0 = 0)  = 0$. Since the chain is irreducible you only need to check recurrence for any state, say 0, and so the chain is recurrent.

Comment: Could you provide a source for the (quite mysterious) considerations about $m_1$ and $m_2$ in relation with recurrence?

Comment: @Did: this appears in a solution to an exercise I have found, but cannot quite follow, so it's not a general approach I think but specific for this example.

Comment: Which exercise? A solution you found where?

Comment: @Bunder: why is $\mathbb P(X_i=i,i\geq 1 \vert X_0=0) = \mathbb P(T_0 < \infty \vert X_0=0)$? $T_0$ is the first hitting time, isn't it? But for the event $\{X_i=i,i\geq 1\}$, $X$ never hits $0$ again, so I would rather think $\{X_i=i,i\geq 1\} \subset \{T_0 > \infty\}$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @Did: It's a solution to an exercise in my course given by the assistant. The exercise is fully stated above and I picked that case for which I don't understand his reasoning. Thanks for helping!

Comment: What happens to this question? Is it dead? If so, close it.